# How to show a button in a pop up message in Python and how to interact?

Tags: python, pyqt5, folium

I'd like to make a button in a pop up message. I use PyQt5 module and a message in pop up. But when I make a button in the message, my pop up message is in **for**

```
import sys
import io
import folium # pip install folium
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout,             QVBoxLayout, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView # pip install       PyQtWebEngine
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

****some codes***
        for c in range (len(flight_df)):
        
            tooltip1 =str(flight_df['x'][c])+"*** "+str(flight_df['y'][c])+"*** "+str(flight_df['name'][c])
            folium.Marker([flight_df['x'][c],flight_df['y'][c]], popup=flight_df['x'],tooltip=tooltip1).add_to(m)

        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)

        webView = QWebEngineView()
        webView.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
        layout.addWidget(webView)


****some other codes****
```

My code is above. Can you help me how can I add a follow button in pop up screen and how can I see if button work

Comment: please provide a [mre]. what is the meaning of *how can I take an interact from it*.

Comment: I have a map window and a location on the mat. When I click on the location, pop up com. I'd like to add a button on this pop up screen like "Follow it". How can I take a note like "Following".?

Comment: From what I understand you want a button to be placed in the popup and that button must invoke a function, but my question is, what information should it do?

Comment: It should do only print yes you clicked. Because I write a code for drone follower

Answer (score 0):

PyQt comes with a message box dialog built into it for these purposes.
The following code worked for me

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import Qt

from PyQt5.Qt import QMessageBox

a = Qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Qt.QWidget()
window.resize(320, 240)
window.setWindowTitle("Hello World!")


result = QMessageBox.question(window, 'TITLE', 'MESSAGE', QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)


window.show()
sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Comment: Where can I locate on the code? I couldnt put in the popup